# "positive" cache when got a user request - ehcache

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am in charged to improve the performance for my webapp, and of course, the solution must be caching.

At the moment, the system have feed rss data which should be a little bit fresh, the problem is it made so heavy mysql loading. I cached it 1 minutes with ehcache, actually. It means after 1 minutes, the data will be expired, when the unlucky user come, their experiences will be slow down than normal .

The configuration of ehcache like this:

```
<cache name="news.list" maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000" eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="60" statistics="true"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO">
</cache>
```

I called it as negative caching, I'm thinking about positive caching,too. If the cache of data was expired, it still return old cache data and make a parallel task to fill up-to-date data for other customer come later.

Does ehcache have any technique to support that?

Any idea is welcome,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a so called [refresh-ahead](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.8.4/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/refreshahead/RefreshAheadCache.html) cache. With this so you can instruct your cache to consistently look for expired entries and refresh them in the background. So by the time your users come around, they will likely find fresh (instantly-usable) information pre-loaded for them.

You still need to be careful with your overall configuration. **Caching done badly can cause performance degradation to your app.** You should not apply any kind of caching method without fully understanding its scope and doing tests when you can.

Comment: Thank you, very detail and helpful .